# Slow query when using ORDER BY in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgresql-9.5, postgresql-performance

This query

```
SELECT *
FROM
  ( SELECT event_id
   FROM events_201806
   WHERE registry_name='$VCZN://externalcenter/ninaExtCenter_ZN'
   UNION ALL SELECT event_id
   FROM events_201805
   WHERE registry_name='$VCZN://externalcenter/ninaExtCenter_ZN'
   UNION ALL SELECT event_id
   FROM events_201804
   WHERE registry_name='$VCZN://externalcenter/ninaExtCenter_ZN'
   UNION ALL SELECT event_id
   FROM events_201803
   WHERE registry_name='$VCZN://externalcenter/ninaExtCenter_ZN') AS ids 
NATURAL INNER JOIN events;
```

Returns 456 results and takes about 20 ms.

Adding ORDER BY

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT event_id
   FROM events_201806
   WHERE registry_name='$VCZN://externalcenter/ninaExtCenter_ZN'
   UNION ALL SELECT event_id
   FROM events_201805
   WHERE registry_name='$VCZN://externalcenter/ninaExtCenter_ZN'
   UNION ALL SELECT event_id
   FROM events_201804
   WHERE registry_name='$VCZN://externalcenter/ninaExtCenter_ZN'
   UNION ALL SELECT event_id
   FROM events_201803
   WHERE registry_name='$VCZN://externalcenter/ninaExtCenter_ZN') AS ids 
NATURAL INNER JOIN events
ORDER BY event_ts DESC;
```

causes the query to take a very long time to complete, about 10 minutes.

Any pointers on how to fix this?

Comment: Unrelated, but: `natural join` is a really bad habit to use. You should use an explicit join (it won't make it faster, but it will make it less error prone)

Comment: Try adding `OFFSET 0` to your inner sub select.

Comment: @EvanCarroll Hmm didn't see to help, thanks though

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Hmmm, didn't think about the drawbacks (column names changing, new columsn), thanks for letting me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting the original (fast) query into a common table expression:

```
with my_events as (
  select *
  from (
    ...
  ) as ids
     join events on ids.event_id = events.id
)
select *
from my_events
order by event_ts desc;
```

CTEs are optimized independently from the rest of the query, so that should run the base query with the fast plan. Ordering the 456 rows should be fairly quick.

Comment: Works very well, thanks @a_horse_with_no_name!